# Integrating Where, Group By and Order By clauses?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I can't seem to figure out why my query won't run.  I suspect the problem is in the where clause but I'm not sure why.

```
SELECT COUNT(PRODUCT_ID), PRODUCT_ID
FROM ORDER_ITEMS
WHERE 'COUNT(PRODUCT_ID)' > 6
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
ORDER BY COUNT(PRODUCT_ID) DESC;
```

I get this error from Oracle Apex: ORA-01722: invalid number

Thank you!

Comment: Try it with `having` instead of using `where` clause and confirm PRODUCT_ID column is a number type.

Comment: I tried using having and still got the same result and PRODUCT_ID is definitely a number type

Comment: @NandhakumarMV - Why does the data type of `PRODUCT_ID` matter? There are no arithmetic operations or inequality tests, etc., performed on `PRODUCT_ID`, they are only counted. You can count values of any data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial problem is that you are comparing a string to a number `'COUNT(PRODUCT_ID)' > 6` which produces the error message. However it appears that you want to filter by the results of an aggregation.

There is another clause to use for this, the `HAVING` clause. This appears after the group by clause, and it can access calculations performed by grouping.

```
SELECT COUNT(PRODUCT_ID), PRODUCT_ID
FROM ORDER_ITEMS
-- where goes here, it cannot access aggregations
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
HAVING COUNT(PRODUCT_ID) > 6
ORDER BY COUNT(PRODUCT_ID) DESC;
```

The where clause occurs before grouping is performed, so it cannot access aggregated values.

Note the `having` clause is not a substitute for a `where` clause they have different functions.

It may be helpful to know that the way we write SQL queries is NOT the sequence of how the clauses are evaluated by the database. That sequence starts with the `from` and `where` clauses, then the `group by`, then the `having`, then the `select` and finally the `order by` i.e.:

```
from
where
group by
having
select
order by
```

I know this may seem weird, but consider that you must get the data first before you can aggregate it, once aggregated we can forget anything not meeting the having clause, then arrange (select) the columns, and finally sequence the remaining rows into the wanted row order.

Comment: please try again, without the single quotes in this line `HAVING COUNT(PRODUCT_ID) > 6`

Comment: I feel like this answer could use an edit, to start by answering the question that was asked (i.e. the single quotes error), and then maybe adding the information about `having` which is relevant, but answers a different question.